# Argument of type "float" is incompatible with parameter of type "const void *"

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to design a basic matrix class having data allocated in device. I am having some problems when inserting an element into the matrix given its row and col. This is my actual code:

```
template <typename CellType_>
class CUDAMatrix {
public:
  using CellType = CellType_;

  CUDAMatrix(size_t rows_, size_t cols_) {
    _rows = 0;
    _cols = 0;
    resize(rows_, cols_);
  }

  ~CUDAMatrix() {
    cudaFree(_data);
  }

  inline size_t rows() const {
    return _rows;
  }

  inline size_t cols() const {
    return _cols;
  }

  inline void _init() {
    _capacity = _rows * _cols;
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc((void**) &_data, sizeof(CellType) * _capacity));
  }

  inline void resize(size_t rows_, size_t cols_) {
    // if size is ok, do nothing
    if (_rows == rows_ && _cols == cols_)
      return;
    _rows = rows_;
    _cols = cols_;
    if (rows_ * cols_ <= _capacity)
      return;
    cudaFree(_data);
    _init();
  }
   
  inline void set(const size_t row, const size_t col, const CellType& val) {
    if (row > _rows || col > _cols) {
      throw std::out_of_range("[Matrix::at] index out of range");
    }
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(_data[row * _cols + col], &val, sizeof(CellType), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
  }

  inline void clear() {
    cudaFree(_data);
    _capacity = 0;
    _cols     = 0;
    _rows     = 0;
  }

protected:
  size_t _cols;
  size_t _rows;
  size_t _capacity;
  CellType* _data;
};

int main() {
  const size_t rows = 620;
  const size_t cols = 480;

  using MyMat = CUDAMatrix<float>;
  MyMat mymat(rows, cols);

  for (size_t r = 0; r < mymat.rows(); ++r) {
    for (size_t c = 0; r < mymat.cols(); ++c) {
      mymat.set(r, c, 1.f);
    }
  }
}
```

How I can take an element from host and copy it to device? I am getting the error `argument of type "float" is incompatible with parameter of type "const void *"`. The error arise here when I call `cudaMalloc`.

Comment: Does the error also mention which line of code is responsible?

Comment: btw asking for "some references" is offtopic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cudaMemcpy` requires pointer as src and dst, `_data[index]` does not return a pointer. The right way should be:

```
cudaMemcpy(&_data[row * _cols + col], &val, sizeof(CellType), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cudaMemcpy(_data[row * _cols + col], val, sizeof(CellType), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)
```

While almost all possible `memcpy` require pointers for sources and targets, you are attempting to pass cell and `val` values. You should pass the pointer to cell and `&val`.

```
cudaMemcpy(&_data[row * _cols + col], &val, sizeof(CellType), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)
```